# Find Last Row Cell in Spreadsheets (CALC, excel) with formula, based on the last entry (text / number)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, calc

Find Last Cell in Spreadsheets (CALC, excel) with formula, based on the last entry. My solution for this problem was this one: B$24 is the criteria for last entry in a row. (B$24="goodforyou"). The number"-23" is for adjustmnet reasons. You may change it.

This solution applies only if YOU KNOW what is the last ROW entry! Has anyone else a better solution?

```
=LARGE(IF(B$2:B$1070=$B$24;ROW(B$1:B$1067)+ROW(B$24)+0);ROWS(B2:B2))-23
```

Comment: Try finding the first empty cell with Match() [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037467/find-the-first-empty-cell-in-the-same-column-row)

Comment: this work? `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Comment: @WhiteHat Going with VBA `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will be faster... but I doubt that's what he is looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(B1:B9999<>"");ROW(A:A))
```

Should do the trick pretty quick...
No need to know what is in the last cell.

Answer (score 1):

To find the last occurence of the value in **B24** in column **B**, use the *Array Formula:*

```
=MAX(IF(B:B=B$24,ROW(B:B)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.