# Find last populated entry in row

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, calc

I'm using libre office calc but im hoping the formula will be the same. I simply want to find the last populated value in a row and display it elsewhere. The row is left to right and may have empty values.

I've [tried other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465398/find-last-row-cell-in-spreadsheets-calc-excel-with-formula-based-on-the-last) and tried [RTFM](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC) but i don't think I am searching the correct thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the **column index** of the last populated cell, try the following [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.3/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC) (arbitrarily assuming your data lives in row `A1:ZZ1`):

> `=MAX(IF(A1:ZZ1<>"";COLUMN(A1:ZZ1)))`

The following array formula does the same, just with an additional translation of the column index to the **column's name**:

> `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MAX(IF(A1:ZZ1<>"";COLUMN(A1:ZZ1)));4);"1";"")`

[image]

This is a combination of the following sources (Credits...):

- [Dirk Reichel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34471643/342546) on [Find Last Row Cell in Spreadsheets (CALC, excel) with formula, based on the last entry (text / number)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34465398/342546)
- [John Sun's post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=238272&sid=f60c12b1ec12ae591554391bd8284b77#p238272) on [OpenOfficeForums Thread "Derive Column Letter from Formula"](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=54493)

### EDIT

To dynamically get the value of the last populated cell in Row 1, just embed the first formula into a `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, <formula>))` clause. `ADDRESS(1, <formula>)` creates a cell reference, `INDIRECT()` gets the value based on that cell reference. So, the complete (first) formula would look like this:

> `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;MAX(IF(A1:ZZ1<>"";COLUMN(A1:ZZ1)))))`

Complete example:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I get these to work. Do you have any idea how I can (inline preferably) use the result in my final function `=RESULT1` if my row is row 1, to show the value of `Z1` in cell `A3`?

Comment: @myol: I'm not sure if if i got you right - do you want to get the value of the last populated cell? Is yes, my supplementary remarks may be helpful :-)