# Find the location of the first blank cell in a column with header rows

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the location (row number) of the first blank cell in a column of data. Previous questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037467/find-the-first-empty-cell-in-the-same-column-row)) have helped, but by data contains header rows (7 in this case), which may be blank. Therefore, I am only interested in blank cells from row 8.

My attempts so far have tried the formula below, but thought it seems to create the `lookup_array` I want, it doesn't work with `match_type` set to -1. Don't understand why.

```
=MATCH(8, IF(ISBLANK(A:A), ROW(A:A), 0),-1)
```

This just gives `#N/A` for some reason. The `IF` statement appears to return the correct data, e.g. `{0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,13,0,...}` for blanks in rows 3, 5, 9 & 13, but expect the `MATCH` to return 9, as the smallest match greater than 8.

PS - It's important that only the row is referenced, as I don't know how long the data block will be and the formula should work with any length data.

Comment: You can replace `A:A` with `A8:A` to start at row 8.

Comment: Is that syntax limited to recent Excel versions? I'm "stuck" with 2010.

Comment: I also tried `=MATCH(TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(A:A), ROW(A:A), 0)>7,0)` (for a version using match_type=0) which returns the right answer in the function dialog popup, but the formula still returns `#N/A` for the cell value.

Answer (score 0):

As pnuts commented in the answer you linked, you can use the following formula:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A2:A1048576),0,0),0)
```

in your case just change the 2 to the first row you want to count from:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A8:A1048576),0,0),0)
```

This will give you the first position of the empty blank, starting from the 8th Row. If it is in A9, this will return "2".

The alternative you had in your comment:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(A:A), ROW(A:A), 0)>7,0)
```

also works but MUST be entered as an array formula by pressing the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> when entering the formula:

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(A:A), ROW(A:A), 0)>7,0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are populated by a formula use

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(*"RANGE"*=""),0)
```